# React - ref retorna null em manipulador de evento

Tags: javascript, react

Estou desenvolvendo com *React* a um tempo mas não havia encontrado motivos pra usar de *refs*, decide ler mais a fundo a documentação e me deparei com vários exemplos que indicam aos desenvolvedores onde se faria sentido o uso das mesmas. Na documentação o exemplo usado é o de um elemento DOM, no caso um *button* totalmente génerico mas o qual faria sentido manter uma referência.

```js
const FancyButton = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <button ref={ ref } { ...props }>{ props.children }</button>
));

const ref = React.createRef();

function App(props) {

    function onClick(e) {
        console.log(ref.current);
    }

    return (
        <FancyButton ref={ ref } onClick={ onClick }>Clique aqui!</FancyButton>
    );

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Como um teste pra verificar o que era retornado de uma referência implementei um manipulador de evento de clique que simplesmente imprimiria o valor de *ref.current* mas somente recebo o valor *null*. Alguém poderia me dizer onde estou errando?

Comment: Faltou passar o refs para o fancybutton dentro de Apps. `<FancyButton ref={ref}>Click me!</FancyButton>`. Na [doc](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) é demonstrado o uso de forwardRef.

Comment: Desculpe havia esquecido de colocar no exemplo mas no meu teste o mesmo ainda não funciona.

Comment: Então, eu tbm testei só para ter certeza, nao é comum eu usar o createRef, geralmente utilizo mais o useRef, mas aqui ocorreu o esperando, o elemento é retornado. Segue o [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/test-creteref-element-fsky3)